# How to split a vector into other two containing the N random chosen elements and the rest?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to have a function that chooses N random elements from the input vector and returns as output parameters two vectors: one containing the chosen elements and one containing the remaining elements.

I have created a template that looks like here:

```
template< class T > void splitVector(const std::vector< T >& vecIn, int nbIn, std::vector< T >& chosenOut, std::vector< T >& remainedOut)
{
    if (nbIn >= vecIn.size())
    {
        chosenOut = vecIn;
        remainedOut.clear();
        return;
    }

    if (nbIn <= 0)
    {
        chosenOut.clear();
        remainedOut = vecIn;
        return;
    }

    cv::RNG randomChooser(cv::getTickCount()); // this is an OpenCV RNG, but it can be any other
    chosenOut.clear();
    remainedOut = vecIn;
//  I have also tried these approaces too, but none works
//  remainedOut.clear();
//  std::copy(vecIn.begin(), vecIn.end(), remainedOut.begin());
//  remainedOut.insert(remainedOut.begin(), vecIn.begin(), vecIn.end());
    int index;
    size_t listSize = vecIn.size();
    fs::path name;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nbIn; ++i)
    {
        index = randomChooser.next() % listSize;
        name = remainedOut[index];
        remainedOut.erase(remainedOut.begin() + index);
        chosenOut.push_back(name);
        listSize = remainedOut.size();
    }
}
```

1. I am getting an error at runtime: `bad_alloc` when `remainedOut = vecIn;`.
2. If I have tried the `insert` I am getting the same error when inserting.
3. If I use `copy` it works but I am getting an error when `name = remainedOut[index];`

I think it is something about the allocation. When I called the function I have created the output vectors like this:

```
std::vector< boost::filesystem::path > chosen;
std::vector< boost::filesystem::path > remained;
splitVector< boost::filesystem::path >(elements, 12, chosen, remained);
```

Can anyone help me to make this work? I would like to do all the things in the function (if it is possible). Shall I use assign? Or how would you suggest me to do this in the best way?

---

**EDIT:**

Why even If I do

```
//... the ifs in the function
std::vector< T > tmpVec = vecIn; // here
std::random_shuffle(tmpVec.begin(), tmpVec.end());
chosenOut.insert(chosenOut.begin(), vecIn.begin(), vecIn.begin() + nbIn);
remainedOut.insert(remainedOut.begin(), vecIn.begin() + nbIn, vecIn.end());
```

I get the `std::bad_alloc` error at the mentioned line?

Even copy c-tor is throwing that error...

Comment: Populate, shuffle, split.

Comment: I see more than one meaning of your comment: 1. order; 2. search on google; Can you be more explicit, please?

Comment: To shuffle, use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: Ok, there is a function to do the shuffle, but how to get the 2 output vectors if insert and copy do give errors?

Comment: The problem seems to be at the input, the vector is not ok, that is why I am getting the error. I will close the question and maybe ask another one that shows the true problem. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try, this will return a pair of pointer, not reference though:

```
template< class T > std::pair<vector<T>* , vector<T>* > splitVector(const std::vector< T >& vecIn, int nbIn)
{
    auto vecC = vecIn;
    std::random_shuffle(vecC.begin(), vecC.end());
    auto vec1 = new vector<T>(vecC.begin(), vecC.begin()+nbIn);
    auto vec2 = new vector<T>(vecC.begin()+nbIn, vecC.end());
    return std::make_pair(vec1, vec2);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the +1 in vec2, because ranges are half-open (end is excluded)

Comment: ok, I thing that there is a  problem because of `boost::filesystem::path` and the `const` in front of the input vector